# GWT Error: 'com.google.gwt.widgetideas.client.FastTree$DefaultResources' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)

Tags: java, gwt

I'm new to GWT and using version 2.4.  In my EntryPoint class, I have this line ...

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    FastTree.addDefaultCSS();
```

which is dying mercilessly with the below exception.  I'm launching my application through Eclipse (Debug As -> Web Application).  Below is my .gwt.xml file ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='sampletreeapp'>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

    <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
    <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
    <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>

    <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
    <entry-point class='com.google.gwt.sample.sampletreeapp.client.SampleTreeApp'/>

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
    <source path='client'/>
    <source path='shared'/>

    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.widgetideas.WidgetIdeas' />
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.libideas.LibIdeas' />
</module>
```

Any ideas how to heal the pain? - Dave

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.google.gwt.widgetideas.client.FastTree$DefaultResources' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
at com.google.gwt.widgetideas.client.FastTree$DefaultResources.<clinit>(FastTree.java:66)
at com.google.gwt.widgetideas.client.FastTree.addDefaultCSS(FastTree.java:100)
at com.google.gwt.sample.sampletreeapp.client.SampleTreeApp.onModuleLoad(SampleTreeApp.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
at com.google.gwt.libideas.resources.rebind.AbstractResourceBundleGenerator.generate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:647)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:78)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:268)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ShellModuleSpaceHost.rebind(ShellModuleSpaceHost.java:141)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:585)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:455)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
at com.google.gwt.widgetideas.client.FastTree$DefaultResources.<clinit>(FastTree.java:66)
at com.google.gwt.widgetideas.client.FastTree.addDefaultCSS(FastTree.java:100)
at com.google.gwt.sample.sampletreeapp.client.SampleTreeApp.onModuleLoad(SampleTreeApp.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a version of the incubator library (WidgetIdeas and LibIdeas) that is not compatible with GWT 2.4. In recent versions of GWT most of the features from the incubator have been moved to GWT itself, so you might not even need the library. For example you're using `FastTree`, which is available in GWT 2.4 as `CellTree`. So you should use `CellTree`. In general you should not use the GWT incubator as it's not maintained.